# Can we store a lambda expression inside a variable and use it as a function in java?

Tags: java, variables, lambda

Can we store a lambda expression in java inside a variable and use that variable as a normal function by calling the variable inside the scope it has been declared?

Comment: Is something stopping you from trying it yourself?

Answer (score -1):

In a word, yes.

E.g.:

```java
Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x + 1;

int result = f.apply(1);
```